# Ajax : check email availability with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

if I input an email that is not in the database, always the same alert with the alert if the email is in the database. What's wrong with my coding ?

[image]

I input email 'irsyadfahmy@gmail.com' and I enter the result instead 'Email Address can used' should 'Email Address Already in Use'.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- sweet alert --> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweetalert.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <!-- end sweet alert --> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#email').blur(function(){
                var email = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type    : 'POST',
                    url     : 'check-email.php',
                    data    : 'email='+email,
                    success : function(data){
                        if(data==0)
                        {
                        swal({
                            title: "Email Address can used",
                            text: "",
                            type: "success"
                        });     
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            swal({
                            title: "Email Address Already in Use",
                            text: "",
                            type: "warning"
                        }); 
                        }
                    },
                });
            });
        });
            </script>
    </head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" name="form">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required>
</form>
</body>
    </html>
```

check-email.php

```
<?php
include 'libraries/config.php';
$email   = $_POST['email'];

$cekdata=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user_csr WHERE email = '$email'");
?>
```

result :
[image]

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: What do you see in the console when after `console.log(data)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send back the data to the ajax using `echo` or `print` (I use `die()` in this case). I also tend to use `json` to respond. You should check that the email is valid at the very least but you should be binding the email value instead of injecting it into the sql string:

PHP:

```
<?php

include 'libraries/config.php';
# Set a default response
$def = ['alert' => true];
# Remove empty values
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
# First check this is an actual email
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die(json_encode($def));
}
# You should bind/prepare $email, not insert variable into string
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `user_csr` WHERE `email` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
# Fetch the results of the count
$result = $result->fetch_assoc();
# Write json response
die(json_encode([
    # If succeeded, write the count
    'counted' => $result ? $result['count'] : 0
]));
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#email').blur(function(){
            var email = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'check-email.php',
                data: 'email='+email,
                success: function(response){
                    // Parse response
                    response = JSON.parse(response);
                    // See if alert is set (email is not valid)
                    if(typeof response.alert !== "undefined") {
                        // Set an program alert
                        alert('A program error occurred.');
                        // Stop
                        return false;
                    }
                    var counted = response.counted;
                    swal({
                        title: (counted == 1)? "Email Address Already in Use" : "Email Address can used",
                        text: "",
                        type: (counted == 1)? "warning" : "success"
                    });
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your program scenario, just swap the if body in success function, here code snippet

```
                    success : function(data){
                    if(data==0)
                    {
                    swal({
                        title: "Email Address Already in Use",
                        text: "",
                        type: "warning"
                    }); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    swal({
                        title: "Email Address can used",
                        text: "",
                        type: "success"
                    });     

                    }
                },
```

Answer (score -1):

Please review this code where i have some PHP code and JS code as well

```
<?php

include 'libraries/config.php';

$email   = isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';

if(!empty($email)){

   $cekdata=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user_csr WHERE email = '$email'");

   return $cekdata->num_rows;  // if email found it returns 1 else 0

}else{
   return 0;
}
```

And Finally you need to check the return value in response

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#email').blur(function () {
        var email = $(this).val(); 
        if(email==""){ 
            alert('Please enter email address'); 
            return false; 
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'check-email.php',
            data: 'email=' + email,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 0)
                {
                    swal({
                        title: "Email Address can use",
                        text: "",
                        type: "success"
                    });
                } else
                {
                    swal({
                        title: "Email Already Exists",
                        text: "",
                        type: "warning"
                    });
                }
            },
        });
    });
});

</script>
```